# How to trigger Invokehttp processor only when flow files pass to downstream?

Tags: apache-nifi, druid

I have a workflow where I will be getting some number of flowfiles in a day, the flow files will be invoking a druid API to submit a task. I want to limit the flowfile rate that passes my InvokeHttp processor to 2 flowfiles and once these two files pass downstream the invokeHttp should stop.When these 2 files are ingested into druid I am getting a status as success. Only when I get success the invokehttp should trigger again and send 2 flow files to downstream.This is a loop until all my flowfiles have been processed.

Is there a possible way to do it through API's or any scripts?